# js - access parent object after attaching a property to it

Tags: javascript

```
obj = {foo: 'foo'}

obj2 = {
  bar: ()=> console.log(this.foo)
}

obj.bar = obj2.bar

obj.bar()
```

What can I do to make `obj.bar()` produce `'foo'`?

Essentially, what I'm trying to do is to create an object and some time later attach a method to it that will be able to access data in the original object.

**Update**
What if I have multiple methods in `obj2` and want to add them as a group to `obj1`? Then the solution for the 1st situation will not suit.

```
obj = {foo: 'foo'}

obj2 = {
  bar: function() {
    console.log(this.foo);
  },
  baz: function() {
    return smth();
  },
  etc: function() {
    return smth();
  }
};

obj.barMethods = obj2;

obj.barMethods.bar();
```

Comment: This should work. What is the actual result?

Comment: `undefined` as `this` is Window object

Comment: Ah right, arrow functions have a different binding behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the classic `function` syntax instead of an arrow function:

```js
obj = {foo: 'foo'}

obj2 = {
  bar: function() { console.log(this.foo) }
}

obj.bar = obj2.bar

obj.bar() // "foo"
```

---

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function
>   expression and **does not bind its own `this`**, arguments, `super`, or
>   `new.target`. These function expressions are best suited for non-method
>   functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), emphasis mine

Comment: @avalanche1 As I said in a comment above: arrow functions have a different binding behavior

Comment: Ok, thank you! This js particularity is VERY misleading... awful! why would they do this??

Comment: @avalanche1 It's incredibly useful though if you know about it. :-)

Comment: I've amended my question to be closer to my real-life case - could you be so kind to look at it?

Comment: Well, the best solution would likely be to define `obj` with a proper prototype in the first place. As a workaround, you could set the prototype of `obj` to `obj2` in flight: `Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, obj2); obj.bar(); // "foo"`. You could also set the context of the function when you call it: `obj.barMethods.bar.apply(obj); // "foo"`